# Why can't I see the rest of my buttons in Tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and coding and I was wondering why can't I see the rest of my buttons. Can someone help me? I'm a total noob at coding.

```
from Tkinter import*

x=Tk()

def message():
    y=Tk()

    y.geometry("375x500")
    label=Label(y,bg="light green")


    recip=Entry(y)
    recip.place(x=90, y=20, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.04)

    to=Label(y,text="To:",bg="maroon", fg="light green", )
    to.place(x=15,y=20, relwidth=0.2,relheight=0.04)

    chat=Entry(y)
    chat.place(x=15,y=300, relwidth=0.7,relheight=0.05)

    send=Button(y,text="send", bg="maroon", fg="light green")
    send.place(x=275,y=300, relwidth=0.2,relheight=0.05)

    q=Button(y,text="Q")
    q.place(x=15,y=330)

    w=Button(y,text="W")
    w.place(x=35,y=330)

    e=Button(y,text="E")
    e.place(x=55,y=330)

    r=Button(y,text="R")
    r.place(x=75,y=330)

    t=Button(y,text="T")
    t.place(x=95,y=330)

    y=Button(y,text="Y")
    y.place(x=115,y=330)

    u=Button(y,text="U")
    u.place(x=15,y=330)

    i=Button(y,text="I")
    i.place(x=155,y=330)

    o=Button(y,text="O")
    o.place(x=175,y=330)

    p=Button(y,text="P")#10

    label.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)   
    y.mainloop()


button=Button(x,text="sample", command=message)

button.pack()

x.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can't have two main windows eg. Tk(). Use Toplevel() to create another window.
Also you stick to one geometry manager eg. pack/place/grid. Change either place to pack or the other way round. Also the button `p` isn't placed at all. This I realise are a few side problems but they are important to fix. Look at the other two answers to fix your button.

Comment: be careful with how you word the advice to "stick to one geometry manager" -- you can use them all in an application as a whole, you just can't mix `grid` and `pack` with the same parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as stated by Lafexlos, is that you are overwriting your instance of `Tk()` to add the buttons to.

I believe you should dynamically create your buttons instead of doing each 1 individually. And then given them a command that will return the corresponding letter.

I have used pack instead of place because I believe it suits this kind of program best for how the buttons are created. You will also need to make sure not to use `grid, place and/or pack` in the same `Tk()` instance as you'll find this causes problems for it.

```
import tkinter as tk


def open_message():
    message = tk.Toplevel(root, bg = "light green")
    message.minsize(300, 400)

    keys = 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'

    # frames for the keyboard
    keyboard = tk.Frame(message, bg = "light green")
    row1 = tk.Frame(keyboard)
    row2 = tk.Frame(keyboard)
    row3 = tk.Frame(keyboard)

    row1.pack()
    row2.pack()
    row3.pack()

    # Dynamically creates each button
    # position of button depends on key index
    # using index the button is assinged to the relative row
    # this only includes letters. To add more, add to keys string
    # and change the values to determine the assigned row
    for idx, letter in enumerate(keys):
        if idx < 10:
            btn = tk.Button(row1, text=letter, command=lambda i=idx: get_letter(i))
        elif idx < 19:
            btn = tk.Button(row2, text=letter, command=lambda i=idx: get_letter(i))
        else:
            btn = tk.Button(row3, text=letter, command=lambda i=idx: get_letter(i))

        btn.pack(side = tk.LEFT)


    to_frame = tk.Frame(message, bg = "light green", padx = 40)
    send_frame = tk.Frame(message, bg = "light green", padx = 40)

    tk.Label(to_frame, text="To:", bg="maroon", fg="light green", relief = tk.RAISED).\
                       pack(side = tk.LEFT, ipady = 3)

    recip = tk.Entry(to_frame)
    recip.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    chat = tk.Entry(send_frame)
    chat.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    send = tk.Button(send_frame, text="send", bg="maroon", fg="light green")
    send.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

    to_frame.pack(fill = tk.X, expand=True)
    # I imagine your text widget would be packed here
    keyboard.pack()
    send_frame.pack(fill = tk.X, expand=True)

    # Nested function to print values using keys
    def get_letter(i):
        # will print the letter depending on the button pressed
        print(keys[i])

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root,text="sample", command = open_message)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```